# "line at infinity" in projective plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

("Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach" by Thomas Garrity)

I am struggling with Exercise 1.4.12.1 in the above, which I quote with some context:

[image]

Here is my intuitive thinking:

- (a) lines in $\mathbb{C}^3$ with some elevation from the x-y plane (ie where $z \neq 0$) are reduced to a single point, where that point is the intersection of the line with the plane $z =1$. This point is unique (which is why $\phi$ in 1.4.9 is a bijection), and it is labelled $(x:y:1)$
- (b) the lines in the x-y plane in 1.4.11/1.4.12 do not hit $z=1$. Those lines are of the form $( x,\frac{-ax-c}{b},0 )$ , or alternatively $( bx,-ax-c,0 )$

But then :

- I do not understand why under $\phi$ these lines are assigned the point stated in 1.4.12.1
- even so, why are such points necessarily distinct from those assigned to lines for the prior case, where  $z \neq 0$ ?

EDIT #1: I add the rest of the exercise (ie 1.14.12.3)  to show the conclusion reached by the author. Personally, I feel able to reach that conclusion directly from my (b) above:

[image]

Comment: Note that $(x:y:z)=(\lambda x:\lambda y:\lambda z)$ if $\lambda\neq 0$ (in your problem, take advantage of $b\neq 0$)

Comment: Personally, i think that the point assigned to (bx,−ax−c,0) should just be the one assigned to (1,(−ax−c)/(bx),0) , ie (1:(−ax−c)/(bx):0) , with (1:−a/b:0) the point assigned to the case x = infinity. Then i would understand why such points are  distinct from those for lines with elevation, since the last component is (_:_:0) rather than (_:_:1)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.... The point is not $(bx:-ax-c: {\color{red} 0})$, it is $(bx:-ax-c: {\color{red} b})$, which is the same thing as $(x:-(ax+c)/b: {\color{red} 1})$.

Comment: I have added the conclusion reached by the author in an edit. Personally I feel able to skip 1.4.12.1/2 and reach 1.4.12.3 directly given my (b), although i am probably wrong in doing so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\phi: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2 \setminus \{z = 0\}$ sends $(x,y)$ to $[x:y:1]$.

Your line $\ell$ is defined as $y = (-ax-c)/b$, and therefore

$$ \phi((x, (-ax-c)/b)) = [x: (-ax-c)/b: 1] = [bx : -ax-c: b].$$

In your intuitive thinking, you should think on the affine plane as having $z$ coordinate equal to 1. In other words, in $\mathbb{C}^3$, you are in the plane $z=1$!

An affine line in $\mathbb{C}^2$ therefore corresponds to a plane in $\mathbb{C}^3$: each point $(x_0, y_0)$ of the line in $\mathbb{C}^2$ corresponds in $\mathbb{C}^3$ to the line passing through the origin and the point $(x_0, y_0, 1)$, and putting together all the points in $\mathbb{C}^2$ (resp. lines in $\mathbb{C}^3$) you get a line (resp. a plane). So the affine line in $\mathbb{C}^2$ not only intersects the plane $z=1$, but is cointaned in it!